# JQuery .each() loop is not incrementing index of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.size-inputs').each(function(index, element) {
    let i = 0;
    element.value = productSizes[i];
    i++;
});
```

Here, for each of the inputs of the same class, I want to change their value depending on my array. So the first input would have the value of productSize[0], the second input would have productSize[1]. But the problem is, both inputs end up having the value of productSize[0]. How do I fix this?

Comment: You declare `let i = 0` every time this executes. So it starts at zero, in two lines it increments to one, then the next time it starts at zero again. You can take the declaration outside but also you can probably just use the `index` parameter.

Comment: Move the `let i=0;` outside the `.each` or simply use the passed `index`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `index` parameter.

```
$('.size-inputs').each(function(index, element){
    element.value = productSizes[index];
});
```